# Apache Drill query mongo array field type with IN() operator

Tags: sql, mongodb, apache, apache-drill

Take the following document structure for sample where I need to do a SELECT ... WHERE field IN(values) in drill.

```
{   "CD_MATRICULA" : 12,
    "USUARIO" : {
        "ID_SITUACAO" : 1,
        "PUBLICOALVO" : [ 84,85,86,87,88,89 ]
    }
},
{   "CD_MATRICULA" : 14,
    "USUARIO" : {
        "ID_SITUACAO" : 1,
        "PUBLICOALVO" : [ 90,91,92,93,94 ]
    }
},
{   "CD_MATRICULA" : 122,
    "USUARIO" : {
        "ID_SITUACAO" : 0,
        "PUBLICOALVO" : [ 20,300,400,500,600 ]
    }
}
```

To find documents by USUARIO.PUBLICOALVO value, I can use the mongo query that follows:

```
db.getCollection('xxx').find({'USUARIO.PUBLICOALVO': {$in: [ 84, 85, 90, 94, 500 ]}})
```

it works fine, returning all the docs by IN() comparsion of lists.

But, when I try to execute the same mongo query in SQL of DRILL, I do this:

```
SELECT * FROM xxx WHERE xxx.USUARIO.PUBLICOALVO IN(84, 85, 90, 94, 500);
```

But this query fails, with the message:

```
Error in expression at index -1.  Error: Missing function implementation: [equal(INT-REPEATED, INT-REQUIRED)].  Full expression: --UNKNOWN EXPRESSION--.
```

How I can write this king of filter IN() in the drill sql syntax ?

thanks a lot

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Apache Drill's Mongo storage plugin does not support the IN operator.

The [original documentation for Apache Drill's Mongo storage plugin](https://drill.apache.org/blog/2014/11/19/sql-on-mongodb/) stated:

> As of now, predicate pushdown is implemented for the following filters: >, >=, <, <=, ==, !=, isNull and isNotNull.

Looking at the [latest version of the code](https://github.com/apache/drill/blob/master/contrib/storage-mongo/src/main/java/org/apache/drill/exec/store/mongo/MongoFilterBuilder.java) this remains the case:

```
switch (functionName) {
    case "equal":
      compareOp = MongoCompareOp.EQUAL;
      break;
    case "not_equal":
      compareOp = MongoCompareOp.NOT_EQUAL;
      break;
    case "greater_than_or_equal_to":
      compareOp = MongoCompareOp.GREATER_OR_EQUAL;
      break;
    case "greater_than":
      compareOp = MongoCompareOp.GREATER;
      break;
    case "less_than_or_equal_to":
      compareOp = MongoCompareOp.LESS_OR_EQUAL;
      break;
    case "less_than":
      compareOp = MongoCompareOp.LESS;
      break;
    case "isnull":
    case "isNull":
    case "is null":
      compareOp = MongoCompareOp.IFNULL;
      break;
    case "isnotnull":
    case "isNotNull":
    case "is not null":
      compareOp = MongoCompareOp.IFNOTNULL;
      break;
}
```

FWIW, `IN` is not the only unsupported operator; the `LIKE` operator is not supported yet either though there is an [open issue](https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/DRILL-2734) against the Drill Mongo storage plugin for that.

So you coult ...

- Implement the `IN` operator yourself. There's a patch attached to [this issue](https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/DRILL-2734) which might provide some with guidance on how to implement the `IN` operator
- Raise an issue against the [Drill project](https://issues.apache.org/jira/secure/RapidBoard.jspa?rapidView=185&projectKey=DRILL) specifying `Component=Storage - MongoDB`
- Implement your `IN` as a series of ORed equals e.g. instead of `WHERE xxx.USUARIO.PUBLICOALVO IN (84, 85, 90, 94, 500)` you could try `WHERE xxx.USUARIO.PUBLICOALVO = 84 OR xxx.USUARIO.PUBLICOALVO=85 ...`